# on form submit I'm unable to get value field

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a `form` in which 2 `input` fields are there,

**step1:** I will fill 2 `input fields` on `submit` I `log` it to `console`, but I see there is no value associated to the typed `input`.

**Question:** How can I get set value during `form submission` like this `value="your typed value"`.

ALL I want is `typed value` after `form submit`

Here is my code:

```js
$('#sub').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($('form').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <p>
        <span>Enter you name</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" id=""/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>Enter your city</span>
        <input type="text" name="city" id=""/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit"  id="sub" value="SUBMIT ME SIR" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Why have you used e.preventDefault()? Can you try commenting it and check again?

Comment: You need to set unique ID values

Comment: @Alex, without `id` i want to achieve this.  is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the value of the input and pressing "SUBMIT ME SIR" it still returns the HTML with the default values.

```js
$('#sub').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$("input,select,textarea").each(function() {
  if($(this).is("[type='checkbox']") || $(this).is("[type='radio']")) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
  }else {
    if ($(this).is("select")) {
      $(this).find(":selected").attr("selected", "selected");
    } else {
      $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
    }
  }
});
  
console.log($('form').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<p>
  <span>Enter you name</span>
  <input type="text" name="name" id=""/>
</p>
<p>
   <span>Enter your city</span>
  <input type="text" name="city" id=""/>
</p>
<p>
   <span>Select your gender</span>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>Female
</p>
<p>
   <span>Select your checkbox</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1"/>check1
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2"/>check2
</p>
<p>
   <span>Selectbox</span>
  <select>
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option value="value2">value2</option>
    <option value="value3">value3</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit"  id="sub" value="SUBMIT ME SIR" />
</p>
</form>
```

Would you please try above snippet? I think it's helpful for you.

Comment: this what i wanted, one `small request can you elaborate it for check group and select box`.  thanks in advance

Comment: @DilipG I have updated my answer. Would you please check it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `console.log($('form').html());` use this:

```
console.log($('form input[type="text"]').val());
```

---

As per your last comment:-

As you don't have `[value]` attribute on the `[type=text]` elements. If you need to show them in `console.log()` then you have to set it explicitly like below:

```js
$('#sub').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $frm = $('form');
  $frm.find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('value', this.value);
  });

  console.log($frm.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <span>Enter you name</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Enter your city</span>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" id="sub" value="SUBMIT ME SIR" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: i want `whole form elements with value set` ..is this possible?

Comment: Yes! but you have to set the attribute.

Comment: @DilipG check the snippet posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `serializeArray()` function available in jQuery.

You can achieve this like,

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
  var formVars = $( this ).serializeArray() ;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formVars));
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Here is a working DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Lepd897h/1/**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeArray()` or `serialize()` function of jQuery to get the data of post in array or querystring format.

```js
$('#sub').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($('form').serializeArray());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <span>Enter you name</span>
    <input type="text" name="nothing" id=""/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="abc" id=""/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit"  id="sub" value="SUBMIT ME SIR" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").on("submit", function(ev) {
console.log("first input " + $(this).eq(0).eq(1).val();
console.log("first input " + $(this).eq(0).eq(1).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get individual values of the form elements you can use the jQuery [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
var elementValue = $('[name=elementName]').val();
var cityValue = $('[name=city]').val();
```

If it's for posting your form data to a backend you need to serialize the form data using jQuery [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
<form id = "customer-data-form">
        <input type="text" name="name" id=""/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="city" id=""/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit"  id="sub" value="SUBMIT ME SIR" />
    </p>
</form>

$('#customer-data-form').serializeArray();
```

This would return a json object with the form data as key value pairs

```
[{"name":"name","value":"NameValue"},{"name":"city","value":"CityValue"}]
```